# Operator can't be applied to 'android.widget.EditText'

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm doing an android "number guessing game", it will generate a random number between 1 to 30 and compare it to the user's input *(EditText inputType:number)* and with a *TextView* it will tell the user if the number is bigger or smaller.

I was trying to compare the input from the user to the real number by doing this:

```
if (num_input == number) {
    t_win.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And it showed this error: **Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText', 'int'**

I tried to fix it by changing the EditText to string or int in these ways:

Change to int

```
       @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0){

            s_title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            t_rules.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btn_start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            strt_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t_introgss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            num_input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Generate random numbers
            int number = 1 + (int)(30 * Math.random());

            // Given trials
            int trials = 3;
            int i, guess;

            int guessNum = Integer.parseInt(num_input);  // Change to INT!

            // Iterate over number of trials
            for (i = 0; i < trials; i++) {

                // If the number is guessed
                if (guessNum == number) {
                    t_win.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

Change to string

```
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0){

            s_title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            t_rules.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btn_start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            strt_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t_introgss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            num_input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Generate random numbers
            int number = 1 + (int)(30 * Math.random());

            // Given trials
            int trials = 3;
            int i, guess;

            String guessNum = num_input.getText().toString(); //Change to STRING

            // Iterate over number of trials
            for (i = 0; i < trials; i++) {

                // If the number is guessed
                if (guessNum == str(number)) {
                    t_win.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

When I use `Integer.parseInt();` it tells me that it can be applied to *EditText* and when I try to change it to string `.getText().toString();` it works but in the operator part I can't seem to change the *int number* to string.

I'm very new to this, any information will help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `int` value from the text of your `EditText`, but not  from the `EditText` itself.

Try changing

```
int guessNum = Integer.parseInt(num_input);  // Change to INT!
```

to

```
int guessNum = Integer.parseInt(num_input.getText().toString());
```